# Deploying a Rails App on Hostgator (Already Have RoR on site)

Tags: ruby, deployment, localhost, passenger

I'm new to RoR, so I understand that the way I should be deploying a rail app is using Passenger. But I've been unable to find a thread where someone did all their development using their webserver/host, it seems everyone develops their app locally, then deploys it. Is there a way to work and edit your rail app directly on the server it's going to be hosted on? I'm using Rubymine to work on my app. (I'm basically trying to see if there is a straightforward way that I can develop code side my app - upload to server, see the results keep developing)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki) is used for such a task.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into it, I just figured out how to set up with Heroku so maybe I'll stick with it for now.